# ColdFusion: Download Will Start Shortly

Tags: coldfusion, download, mime-types, coldfusion-9

I was trying to run this code, and browser ask me to download pdf file which is good, But it was not loading remaining HTML code or you can say I could not see "Thank you Message".

Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Need your help

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=134.pdf"/>
 
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#ExpandPath( './134.pdf' )#"/>
 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Download Now</title>
</head>
```

Thank you for your interest in downloading
this file. Your download should begin shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe show the 'download will begin shortly' message first as a distinct page, which then redirects (JavaScript or meta tag...) to the .cfm that generates the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is load the PDF file immediatly. As stated before you should have a basic HTML Page:

```
<html>
  <head>
       <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=getpdf.cfm?file=123.pdf">
       ..rest of head
  </head>
  <body>
     Download will begin shortly.
  </body>
</html>
```

This getpdf.cfm?file=123.pdf will be

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=134.pdf"/>

<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#ExpandPath( './134.pdf' )#"/>
```

The reason it wont work, is that you browser reads the "headers" and will basically see the file as a PDF file. Like you were downloading a ".pdf". Now you're putting one step in between and let the browser redirect to the PDF download.